# Rounded Corners on Subtract Item in Sketch

Tags: vector, sketch-app

In this awesome shot on [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/1810209-Simple-Fire) by Yoga Perdana, he has rounded angles on the fire tips. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I know he uses Illustrator, but I don't have access to it.

[image]

If anyone has any ideas, that would be wonderful. The only thing I can think of is using scissors to cut the shapes up and then re-attach them, but that is not particularly accurate.

Comment: I can't be sure if he actually did it this way, but it could be done, as the guide lines show, just by placings circles  at the tips.

Comment: It's not as simple as that, as you can see where the circles cut. You get a sharp edge. This is entirely frustrating. Haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Subtract and Union with multiple ovals...

1. Draw 2 ovals.
2. Subtract the top one from the bottom one.
3. Draw a small oval near the top of the half moon, make sure it overlaps the edges of the half moon, duplicate this smaller oval (you will need the 2nd one later).
4. Subtract one of the small ovals from the half moon.
5. Select the half moon and hit Layers / Paths / Flatten (if a warning comes up, flatten it anyway), now double click the top pointy part of the half moon and delete it.
6. And finally select the other small oval and Union it with the half moon.

You should be able to figure out the rest now...

[image]

Download the sketch file [here](http://ge.tt/2LgrKn62/v/0) (note, I just eyeballed the 2 small ovals at the edge of the half moon, so it's a bit "bubbly", if you take your time you will be able to align it sharp.